# Why postfix does MX lookup for relayhost?

Tags: postfix, email-server, mx-record

I have in the postfix conf:

> relayhost = my.internal.relay.example.org

All the mails transit through this relay.
by default, postfix will try to do a **MX** lookup on *my.internal.relay.example.org*

**Why ?**

It's not the purpose of MX record. I just  want to send through this host, not to the domain.

I know how to fix it (with [] or postfix config).
postfix manuals says how to change the behaviour but not the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SMTP servers delivering mail to MX records comes very naturally.

By also supporting a MX record in the [`relayhost`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost) setting you also automatically get the native **fall-over, load balancing and redundancy** that MX records can provide.

Supporting only a single ip-address or hostname is all fine and dandy when you only have a single relay machine.
When you want to prevent a single point of failure setting up two or more machines using MX records is fairly trivial way to achieve redundancy and HA, compared to setting up a cluster with either fail-over and/or a load balancer on that `relayhost` ip-address/hostname. Using MX records is probably also easier than adding a failover support in Postfix with for instance a optional setting for a `backup_relayhost`.